# Wait simulation time in a non realtime ROS simulation in Python

Tags: quadcopter, ros, simulation, python

I want to control a quadrotor with a Python script and run the simulation as fast as my laptop can, not only in real time. I've modified my world and now the simulation runs with 7-10 real time factor.

My problem is that after acting I want the physics to run for a determinate amount of simulation time, but if I do `time.sleep(steptime)` the sleep is in real time, which is 7-10 times simulation time. So I need to know the real time factor in Python to divide the sleep time. Is there a way to get it?

Comment: I would suggest to log machine time at begininng of the program and keep track of the simulation time, you can then compare them at each iteration

Comment: Thanks N. Staub, your solution is not perfect, but good enougth

Answer (score 1):

@kNo the proper way to use time in ROS is generally to use the [ros::Time](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Time) abstraction and the [/clock topic](http://wiki.ros.org/Clock#Using_Simulation_Time_from_the_.2BAC8-clock_Topic). This way you can use the same program with simulated and real time. Your simulator program should be the one publishing on `/clock`.
Trying to access the real time factor is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: How can make my python script sleep for 5 simulation time seconds using  ros::Time and /clock?

Comment: http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time#Sleeping_and_Rates : `rospy.sleep(5.)` (Assuming your simulator is publishing the simulation time on `/clock`)

Comment: But this will stop simulation for 5 seconds in simulation time, not my script. I want my code to stop for 5 seconds in simulation time. I'm following this tutorial: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-openai-gym-ros-ricardo-tellez/ There, the controller chooses an action, sends it to ROS, unpauses the simulation, sleeps for a time and pauses ROS again. It only works if ROS works in real time.

Comment: @kNo sorry I am getting confused. You say:
" I want my code to stop for 5 seconds in simulation time.  "
This is exactly what `rospy.sleep(5.)` does. Could you give us some sample code to understand what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The pausing of the simulation in the openai gym tutorial is achieved by calling `self.gazebo.pauseSim()` not by the invocation of the `rospy.sleep()`.